# Ordenar una lista en orden alfabético

Tags: java, lista

Dadas do listas: una de con nombres y la otra con valores. Cada elemento de la primera lista está asociado con un elemento de la segunda. Es necesario ordenar los nombres de la primera lista en orden alfabético ascendente y descendente, e imprimirlos con su respectivo valor de la segunda lista.

Lo he hecho de esta forma, pero no ordena de forma alfabética.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Logic {

    public static void studList() {
        ArrayList<String> stud = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Double> uspe = new ArrayList<>();
        stud.add("Peter");
        stud.add("Sophia");
        stud.add("Jacob");
        stud.add("Matt");
        stud.add("Hannah");
        uspe.add(4.5);
        uspe.add(6.3);
        uspe.add(3.8);
        uspe.add(5.5);
        uspe.add(4.7);


        ArrayList<String> list = sortA(stud,uspe);
        for (String s:list) {
            View.printer(s);
        }
        View.printer("-");
        for (int i = list.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            String s = list.get(i);
            View.printer(s);
        }

    }

    private static ArrayList<String> sortA(ArrayList<String> st, ArrayList<Double> us) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        String s;
        for (int i = 0; i < st.size(); i++) {
            s = st.get(i) + ": " + us.get(i);
            list.add(s);
        }
        HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>(list);
        list.clear();
        list.addAll(set);
        return list;
    }

}
```

Comment: Neon actualice mi respuesta por si te interesa esa manera!

Comment: Gracias, lo probaré

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utiliza

```
Collections.sort(list);
for(String temp: list){
    System.out.println(temp);
}
```

Ahora que veo te recomendaria crear un objeto con ambos datos ya que unos tienen relacion con otro

```
public class TuObjeto {
       public String nombre;
       public Double nota;
}
```

Creas una lista de tu objeto

```
ArrayList<TuObjeto> lista = new ArrayList<TuObjeto>();
lista.add(new TuObjeto("Peter", 4.5));
lista.add(new TuObjeto("Sophia", 6.5));
lista.add(new TuObjeto("Jacob", 5.5));
lista.add(new TuObjeto("Matt", 3.0));
```

Y para ordenarla por ejemplo por nombre

```
Collections.sort(lista, new Comparator<TuObjeto>() {
   public int compare(TuObjeto obj1, TuObjeto obj2) {
      return obj1.getNombre().compareTo(obj2.getNombre());
   }
});
```

Y luego

```
for(TuObjeto temp: lista){
    System.out.println(temp.getNombre());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el método burbuja que es el método de ordenamiento más fácil.

```
for(int i=0;i<stud.size();i++){ for(int j=i+1;i<stud.size() ;i++) { if(stud.get(j).compareTo(stud.get(i))<0){ String aux=stud.get(i); Double auxv=use.get(i); stud.set(i,stud.get(j)); uspe.set(i,uspe.get(j)); stud.set(j,aux); uspe.set(j,auxv); } } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Un **ArrayList de Java** se puede ordenar utilizando el método **sort()** de **java.util.Collections**.

Si el *ArrayList* contiene literales (Strings, int, char, ...) y se quiere ordenar ascendentemente, basta con hacer:

```
Collections.sort(theList);
```

Ejemplo:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class OrderArrayListExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List theList = new ArrayList<>();
        theList.add("xxx");
        theList.add("AB");
        theList.add("Abc");

        System.out.println("Lista original:");
        showList(theList);

        Collections.sort(theList);

        System.out.println("Lista ordenada:");
        showList(theList);
    }

    private static void showList(List theList) {
        int size = theList.size();
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
            System.out.println(theList.get(i));
        }
    }

} // class
```

Cuya salida es:

```
Lista original:
xxx
AB
Abc
Lista ordenada:
AB
Abc
xxx
```